# How to update "key" name in hive flutter instead of updating value

Tags: flutter, hive, key

i want to Update the "key" in the flutter hive. but it is updating the value in a flutter.

```
 updateItems(int index, String value){
    final listData=Hive.box(CommonKeys.DB_NAME);
    listData.putAt(index,value);
    final keys=listData.keys;
```

Comment: try doing `await listData.flush()` before `listData.keys`

Comment: Here is solution where first retrieve elements and then delete old and replace with new key

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGhAz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the `key` of element at an index.

Anwser is you can't do that directly (work around is really complicated, tell me if you really need it).

And you shouldn't do that, hive is a `key-value` pair database which mean it designed for read/write `value` using `key` or `index`. So you can't edit `key` or `index`, but you can assign that `value` to a new `key`.

In your case, I recommend you to store as `List` or `Object` instead

```
updateItems(int index, String newKey) {
    final listData = Hive.box(CommonKeys.DB_NAME);
    // This list has only 2 elements, key and value;
    final List keyValuePair = listData.getAt(index);
    keyValuePair[0] = newKey;
    listData.putAt(index, keyValuePair);
}
```

Comment: this will update the value but i want to update the name of key

Comment: @AmeerSafdar Please read my anwser again, as I mention, you shouldn't update name of the key